# User created AMI works on t2 instances but not on c4 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched a t2 type instance, did some work on it, and created an AMI.

Now, when I try to launch a t2 type instance with this AMI, everything works fine.

But when I try the same with a C4 (and also C3) the initialization get's stuck in the "1/2 checks" part.

Anyone has got a clue what's going on here?

Comment: Are you trying to create c4 instance from the AMI of t2?

Comment: Both T2 and C4 instance types are HVM so that should not be the issue... but you didn't mention your OS.  You didn't mention *which* C4 type.  If it has more than 32 cores, it could be related to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compute-optimized-instances.html#compute-instances-cpu-support) but I doubt it -- this scenario would not pass 1/2 checks, I suspect.  Starting an official AMI as t2 and changing it to C4 after launch should prove that this does generally work.

Comment: If 1/2 checks succeed, you may be able to see the [console log](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html)

Comment: I'm using the 2-core c4 instance.
The OS is Ubuntu.
It works fine with the official AMI but fails on my custom made AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this shouldn't be happening. I change instance types while launching an instance from self made AMIs and it works fine.

Can you create another AMI of another instance and try the same?

Also, as you say when you launch it with t2 type it works fine. Launch it again with t2 type, once it launches SSH and check if things are working. Then go ahead and stop (NOT TERMINATE) the instance. Select the instance and then from actions go and change instance type. Now, change instance type to the one you want. Try this and let me know.

[You will see something like this, click here to see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9tpn.png)

Comment: I tried creating a t2 instance with this AMI and then changing it to c4.
It still doesn't work.
I probably changed some OS settings while working on the t2 that made the AMI uncompatible with c4.

And I don't get what you mean by "Can you create another AMI of another instance and try the same?"

Comment: I meant that can you try this for another running EC2 server. Maybe yes, this particular t2 server which you were working with you made some changes and it is incompatible now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. Opening the "System Log" pointed to something wrong with cloud-init.

Digging further pointed me to [Failed to start cloud-init at startup after upgrading to Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328064/failed-to-start-cloud-init-at-startup-after-upgrading-to-python-3-6)

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade jsonpatch
```

Do that and create the AMI again. It would work with c4 now.